# fbpanel: only use one monitor

Tags: x11, multi-monitor, openbox

I am using `fbpanel` in openbox. I have 3 monitors: One in the middle, and two on each side.

Currently `fbpanel` is spread along all 3 monitors.

Can I configure `fbpanel` to only appear on one monitor (monitor 1) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to put `fbpanel` on only one monitor by default but
it's possible to do that using `-x` option that is added by [this
patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/fbpanel/patches/67). After applying this it you can use `-x <MONITOR_NUMBER` to display `fbpanel` on a given monitor, for example:

```
$ ./panel/fbpanel -x 1
```

I tried and it works on my Slackware 14.2 with Fluxbox.

As correctly noted by OP in the comments below this patch cannot be
cleanly applied onto current stable version of `fbpanel` because
implementation of `menu_pos()` function changed.  Instead of looking
for the differences I replaced current implementation of `menu_pos()`
with the implementation from the patch I linked above. To try it:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ardrabczyk/fbpanel
$ cd fbpanel
$ git checkout xinerama-support
```

Then build and optionally install normally.

To apply patches to the Debian package build system:

```
$ cd debian/patches
$ wget http://drabczyk.org/xinerama-support.patch
$ echo xinerama-support.patch >> series
$ cd -
$ dpkg-buildpackage
```

I got:

```
gpg: skipped "Ulises Vitulli <dererk@debian.org>": No secret key
gpg: dpkg-sign.WfacYo70/fbpanel_7.0-3.dsc: clear-sign failed: No secret key

dpkg-buildpackage: error: failed to sign .dsc file
```

but apart from that building succeeds. Install package:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../fbpanel_7.0-3_amd64.deb
```

(I guess that `amd64` might be different on non x86-64 machines).

Comment: which version of `fbpanel` did you patch ? I am on Debian Buster, and the `fbanel` version I am trying to patch is `7.0`. I get: `panel/misc.c: Hunk # FAILED at 713`.

Comment: I patched 6.1 from http://downloads.sourceforge.net/fbpanel/fbpanel-6.1.tbz2

Comment: @MartinVegter: see update

Comment: I need a Debian package that I can install. Can I use your patch, and apply it to the Debian package I am trying to compile ? I am using the standard Debian way to compile a package: `apt-get source fbpanel` and then `dpkg-buildpackage`.

Comment: @MartinVegter: see updated answer

Comment: that works perfectly. Thank you. You are a genius.

Comment: I am now using 3 different fbpanel instances, thanks to your patch. Now I came up with one more request: When using the `taskbar` plugin, is it possible to assign specific application to specific `fbpanel`? I would like to have all applications in `taskbar` on my main monitor, except Thunderbird `taskbar` should appear on right monitor. I would be happy to open new bounty for this request, if you think there might be some solution.

Comment: I don't know what `taskbar` plugin is. Yes, I think you should start a new question or open a ticket on fbpanel project's site.

Comment: I have created new question:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583504/fbpanel-on-multiple-monitors-assign-application-to-different-taskbar